# how to configure project for an android build

Tags: android, build, codenameone

My project is structured with a main project and a separate
library project as a dependent project.  It runs fine under
the emulator in Eclipse.

When I submit an android build request, all the library project's
classes are not found, with a message like this from the compiler

```
[javac] G:\share\projects\eclipse\codenamebsgames\src\checkerboard\CheckerBoard.java:3: error: package online.game does not exist
[javac] import online.game.*;
[javac] ^
```

How would this be structured to make an android build?
Where should I have found this information?

Answer (score 0):

The [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) build server can only compile classes that it receives. If you changed the classpath the servers aren't aware of that and won't be able to compile that.

[cn1lib's](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) work when you place them into the lib directory and select "Refresh Libs". What happens under the hood for this case is that the cn1lib gets extracted into a special set of directories that the `build.xml` packages into the jar when it sends a build.

You can automate this process by changing the cn1lib `build.xml` to copy the cn1lib to the lib directory on compilation.

Comment: With project A depending on project B, both codename1 projects, it seems like the build process isn't smart enough to include the classes for both.

Comment: No the build process has no knowledge of what you changed in the classpath since that's IDE configuration and all our logic is within Ant.